# Training a model with multiple learning rate in PyTorch

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, pytorch

I am new to PyTorch and getting used to some concepts.

I need to train a Neural Network. For optimization, I need to use Adam optimizer with 4 different `learning rates = [2e-5, 3e-5, 4e-5, 5e-5]`

The optimizer function is defined as below

```
def optimizer(no_decay = ['bias', 'gamma', 'beta'], lr=2e-5):
    param_optimizer = list(model.named_parameters())
    optimizer_grouped_parameters = [
    {'params': [p for n, p in param_optimizer if not any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)],
     'weight_decay_rate': 0.01},
    {'params': [p for n, p in param_optimizer if any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)],
     'weight_decay_rate': 0.0}
     ]
     # This variable contains all of the hyperparemeter information our training loop needs
     optimizer = BertAdam(optimizer_grouped_parameters, lr, warmup=.1)
     return optimizer
```

How do I make sure the optimizer uses my specified set of learning rate and returns the best model?

During training, we use the optimizer like below where I don't see a way to tell it to try different learning rate

```
def model_train():
    #other code
    # clear out the gradient
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    # Forward pass
    loss = model(b_input_ids, token_type_ids=None, attention_mask=b_input_mask, labels=b_labels)
    train_loss_set.append(loss.item())
    # Backward pass
    loss.backward()
    # Update parameters and take a step using the computed gradient
    optimizer.step()
```

I know that the `optimizer.step()` internally steps through to optimize the gradient. But how do I make sure the optimizer tries my specified set of learning rate and returns the best model to me?

Please suggest.

Comment: When and where do you want to apply the different the learning rates?

Comment: I want to train 4 models, each with different learning rates, and find the best performing one. So you can think it is equivalent to calling the `optimizer` 4 times as in `optimizer(no_decay = ['bias', 'gamma', 'beta'], lr=2e-5)`, `optimizer(no_decay = ['bias', 'gamma', 'beta'], lr=3e-5)`, `optimizer(no_decay = ['bias', 'gamma', 'beta'], lr=4e-5)` and `optimizer(no_decay = ['bias', 'gamma', 'beta'], lr=5e-5)`

Comment: I see. If you want to train four different models, probably you can just train four times?

Comment: @zihaozhihao so my point is I need to write 4 different optimizers with different  `lr` in the parameter? Because there is no way (not that I know of) to pass parameter while calling `optimizer.step()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to train four times with four different learning rates and then compare you need not only four `optimizer`s but also four `model`s: Using different learning rate (or any other meta-parameter for this matter) yields a different trajectory of the weights in the high-dimensional "parameter space". That is, after a few steps its not only the learning rate that differentiate between the models, but the trained weights themselves - this is what yield the actual difference between the models.

therefore, you need to train 4 times using 4 separate instances of `model` using 4 instances of `optimizer` with different learning rates.